# Changes to python code not recognized

Tags: python, linux, shell

Not really able to find any information on this - I haven't had the problem before, and I've checked what there was to read. Yes I've deleted the .pyc files (obviously), no I'm not loading or importing across multiple modules, I'm trying to run the program directly, I've even committed the changes to Git just to see what it would think - and it's still running an old version of the file. I have no idea where or how to debug this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running it in an interpreter such as ipython, or standalone?

Comment: Directly from shell, with a virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

Very likely it is importing a module somewhere else on your system, assuming you're not running interactive and haven't restart it.

You can try:

```
python -v myprogram.py
```

And it will tell you every single file it imports (including any `.pyc` files).

Comment: Is there a way to redirect that to a file? It's going to take sometime to track this down

Comment: It goes to stderr, assuming you are running unix, just add `2> output.txt` at the end.

Comment: @user3467349  Any luck?  Did this help?

Comment: Nope, and I have a persistence with problem with Django as well apparently, even with caching disabled in Chrome dev, and the __pycache__ removed, and this is for html templates as well btw.